# Converting types of administrative data

Tags: curated-data, entity, version-11

I want to aggregate the data that Wolfram has on ZIP codes and administrative divisions.

I know that administrative divisions have a ZIPCodes property, but it always seems to be empty.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What administrative divisions are you going for? It seems to work fairly well for states, i.e. `Entity["AdministrativeDivision", "Maryland"]["ZIPCodes"]`. It's possible they don't have the available ZIPCodes sorted for every division, unfortunately.

Comment: Counties. The ZIP codes have a FIPS code attached to them, and I can in theory get the county from that, but not sure how to really do that (first too digits are state, last three are county).